# hyper, super and meta. Meaning vs emphasis?

Tags: terminology, hyperoperation

Various mathematical terms use the following prefixes, which are presumably also morphemes:

```
hyper
super
meta
```

These have different dictionary definitions, as I understand it "hyper" refers to 4 or more dimensions, and "super" means "more general" etc...

However in terms such as following:

```
Hyperoperation
Hyperbolic
Superelipse
Metaball
```

Are thease prefixes used more for emphasis than meaning?

Comment: Good question. I am personally puzzled by the use of "hypertranscendental" to refer to something that appears to mean "metatranscendental." "Hypertranscendental" supposedly has as its synonym "transcendentally transcendental" which would imply "meta-," especially given that the relationship between "hypertranscendental functions" i.e. factorial/gamma and "transcendental functions" i.e. exponential is essentially a meta one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Meta" means something like "mentally take a step back and look at what your doing". Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy.
In my experience this is actually what you do when calculating a "hyperoperator". That's why I'd actually argue, "metaoperator" would be a more appropriate name for it.